# PHP stored procedure called and working, page reload doesn't show new data

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I am calling a JS function using a form:

**HTML form:**

```
    <form class="addBlock" method="post" name="addBlockForm">
        <input type="image" id="addBlockBtn" name="addedBlock" src="images/addCassette.png" onclick="addBlock( <?php echo $rowSize + 1 ?>)">
      <input type="hidden" name="specNum" value="<?= $_SESSION["specNum"] ?>">
    </form>
```

**Javascript function:**

```
function addBlock(num)  {

 var form = document.forms['addBlockForm'];

   var nb = document.createElement("input");
   nb.type = "hidden";
   nb.name = "NewBlockNum";
   nb.value = ([num]);
   form.appendChild(nb);

   addBlock.submit();

}
```

Which submits the form, triggering the Php stored procedure and refreshes the page

**PHP Stored procedure:**

```
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && !empty($_POST['NewBlockNum'])) {
      // run the stored procedure for adding a new block

                $callSP_addBlock = "{ CALL AddBlockByID( ?, ?, ? ) }";

            $accID = $row[12];

                $spID = $row[13];

                $nBlockNum = $rowSize + 1;

                $ad_params = array(
                    array($accID,SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                    array($spID, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                    array($nBlockNum, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                    );

                /* Execute the query. */
                $stmt6 = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $callSP_addBlock, $ad_params);

      header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

                if( $stmt6 === false ) {
                    echo "Error in executing statement 6.\n";
                    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
                }
            }
```

The order on the page is the Php, then the JS function definition, and then the html form.

Everything works, however the new added data does not display in the page.

The data display code (that lives after the JS function, but before the form) is this

**PHP Data display code:**

```
    <?php
        do  {
              if (isset($row[15])) {
                        $timeStamp = //date_format($row[15], 'Y-m-d h:i');
                        $printedLabel = 'Printed ';
                        $printedClass = 'printed';
                        } else {
                        $timeStamp = '';
                        $printedLabel = '';
                        $printedClass = '';
                        }
                if (isset($row[14])) {
                        $numOfPieces = $row[14];
                        $piecesLabel = 'Pieces ';
                        } else {
                        $numOfPieces = '';
                        $piecesLabel = '';
                        }

            echo '<div class="'.$printedClass.'cassetteDataRow">
                    '.$row[9].'<br>
                    <form action="#" class="printForm" method="post" name="printedCass"><br>
                        <input type="image" id="cassPrintBtn" name="cPrinted" src="images/cassetteIcon.png" onclick="cassPrint(1)"><br>
                        <input type="hidden" name="'.$row[0].'" value="'.$row[0].'"><br>
                        <input type="hidden" name="specNum" value="'.$specNum.'"><br>
                        <input type="hidden" name="BlockID" value="'.$row[10].'"><br>
                    </form><br/>
                     '.$numOfPieces.' '.$piecesLabel.'<br>
                     '.$printedLabel.' '.$timeStamp.'
                     <input type="image" id="cassInfoBtn" src="images/cassettePrintBtn.png" onclick="div_show('.$row[10].')">
                   </div> <br/>';
          } while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt));

       ?>
```

I have tried moving the php for the stored procedure call below the form (didn't work),I tried form action to `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` and `location.reload();` (also didn't work). 
Any advice is greatly appreciated.Thank you

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Is this code all in the same script file? Is it in the order that you show it? Its not very clear to be honest

Comment: The stored procedure is first, then the JS function, then the data display php do while statement, and then the form

Comment: correction on the data display code sorry